Whats needed to connect from one ubuntu PC to another using ssh?
I recently had a situation where I had to install graphics card driver, plus cuda and bunch of other stuff remotely. it went without a problem(used anydesk to connect remotely and get the job done), but there have been cases where the driver was faulty or after the system it wouldn't boot properly so anydesk or the likes will be out of question.
This made me want to be able to connect using ssh to any PC so in case something went haywire, I can still connect to it, and try to troubleshoot it without having access to GUI.
What steps should I take to do this?

I have tried installing and activating the openssh-server on the pc:
sudo apt install openssh-server
sudo service ssh start   
# check its running
sudo service ssh status


then tried doing ssh 127.0.0.1 to see if I can connect to myself which is ok!

then I tried to get my public IP by doing curl icanhazip.com (e.g. 89.23.234.40)

then I tried to ssh to myself through my public IP I just found in previous step, to simulate connecting to another PC over the internet, which fails!

Doing ssh public-IP just does nothing, it seems its running an endless loop, I dont get an output, I have to use Ctrl-C to quit.
Doing ssh myusername@public-IP gives the error:
ssh: Could not resolve hostname ssh: Name or service



I dont have an static IP address, but it seems the current public IP should suffice as long as its valid (like assigned to me obviously).
What is it that I'm missing and need to do to get this to work?
Im on ubuntu 22.04, but I guess this shouldnt be an issue as I want to learn how to get it to work for any ubuntu version.

Are you directly connected to the internet? If you're on a typical home connection, I'd bet that you're behind a router, and you should enable port-forwarding on the router to forward a public-facing port P (I recommend using something other than 22 to decrease bot traffic, such as 2022) to your Ubuntu system's port 22. How to do exactly that depends on your router model, and isn't related to Ubuntu, so the place to ask that would be [su]. Once you do the port forwarding, however, ssh -p 2022 <public-ip> should work.

Thanks, yes I'm behind a router, so if I enable port-forwarding and use sth other than default port for ssh, I can connect? am I doing all necessary steps, ssh wise correctly though? up to this point I mean?

Yes, since ssh 127.0.0.1 worked. If you want further confirmation, and you have another device connected to the same network (say a phone with an app like Termius), you can test SSH using the private IP (which you can see in the output of ip addr, something like 10.x.y.z or 192.168.y.z). If that works too (which it should), then you can be sure that everything's working on the Ubuntu side.

@muru: can we do port-forwarding from withing ubuntu like this : https://www.debuntu.org/how-to-redirecting-network-traffic-to-a-new-ip-using-iptables/
or do still I need to configure router nonetheless?

That's for when your Ubuntu system is the router.

Thanks a lot really appreciate all the feedback:)
